# How to handle multiple null values in flow using formula

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field

My Scenario is to create a formula field(concatenation) in flows if the values of Email, Mobile and Name of record is not empty. For example, if record has Email & mobile number values but name then the formula field should display a text with combination like "Email <br/> Mobile Number". If the record has only Name is filled then it should be "Name". I can't use decisions for this scenario in flows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Manager tab to create a New Resource. The Resource Type should be Formula, the Data Type should be Text, and the formula should read as follows:

```
{!IF(ISBLANK(Contact.Email),"", Contact.Email & BR())} &
{!IF(ISBLANK(Contact.MobilePhone),"",Contact.MobilePhone & BR())} &
{!Contact.Name}
```

Where `&` means "concatenate text", `BR()` is a new line, and `ISBLANK` checks if a field is empty.

Now, you can use an Assignment element to assign that value to the record, then save it.

Here's some screenshots.

[image: Flow]

---

[image: Formula]

---

[image: Resources]

---

[image: Assignment]